# Multi Array Prep for Charting

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, while-loop, pchart

I searched for answers and could not find one. This is long and complex and looking for someone smart than me to answer.

Here is the situation. Using PHP, SQL, and trying Pchart.

1) Please do not suggest other charting tools. That is a waste of your time and mine. Other charting tool offer JAVA, JAVASCRIPT, JQUERY, and more. They are slick but what I need is simple (server side creation of data created dynamically and rendered using something on server. Why put the load on client side - at least for now while I investigate.

2) This is PHP specific question not the pchart tool.

Here is the scenario.

I have a table with results from swimming.

I can get the data formatted the way I need.

See below prints.

Array (assume this is first array)

```
(
    [0] => Freestyle 50
    [1] => Freestyle 100
    [2] => Backstroke 50
    [3] => Butterfly 50
    [4] => Medley 100
)
```

Array (assume this is second array)

```
(
    [Backstroke 50] => Array
        (
            [2012-11-04] => 51.08
            [2012-11-10] => 52.50
            [2012-11-25] => 55.48
            [2012-12-01] => 47.56
            [2012-12-08] => 44.51
            [2012-12-15] => 49.46
            [2013-01-19] => 47.12
            [2013-11-03] => 42.52
            [2013-11-09] => 40.94
            [2013-11-10] => 42.97
            [2013-11-16] => 41.36
            [2013-12-01] => 45.16
            [2013-12-08] => 40.59
            [2014-01-12] => 37.67
            [2014-02-01] => 37.70
        )

    [Freestyle 50] => Array
        (
            [2012-11-04] => 45.33
            [2012-11-25] => 50.12
            [2013-11-03] => 37.01
            [2013-11-10] => 36.73
            [2013-12-01] => 39.94
            [2014-01-04] => 39.77
            [2014-01-12] => 34.22
            [2014-02-01] => 34.93
        )

    [Freestyle 100] => Array
        (
            [2012-11-04] => 137.73
            [2012-11-10] => 126.86
            [2012-12-08] => 133.65
            [2013-11-03] => 124.14
            [2013-11-10] => 121.94
            [2013-11-16] => 121.10
            [2013-12-01] => 130.99
            [2013-12-07] => 118.27
            [2013-12-08] => 122.44
            [2014-01-04] => 131.38
            [2014-01-11] => 115.95
            [2014-01-18] => 120.06
        )

    [Medley 100] => Array
        (
            [2012-12-01] => 146.66
            [2013-01-19] => 143.88
            [2013-11-03] => 137.37
            [2013-11-09] => 133.05
            [2013-11-10] => 134.69
            [2013-12-01] => 145.29
            [2013-12-07] => 130.15
            [2013-12-08] => 130.92
            [2014-01-12] => 129.33
            [2014-01-18] => 130.81
            [2014-02-01] => 128.57
        )

    [Butterfly 50] => Array
        (
            [2013-12-08] => 46.82
            [2014-01-12] => 43.66
        )

)
```

Array (assume this is third array)

```
(
    [2] => 2012-11-04
    [14] => 2012-11-10
    [1] => 2012-11-25
    [31] => 2012-12-01
    [15] => 2012-12-08
    [26] => 2012-12-15
    [24] => 2013-01-19
    [7] => 2013-11-03
    [28] => 2013-11-09
    [4] => 2013-11-10
    [11] => 2013-11-16
    [3] => 2013-12-01
    [9] => 2013-12-07
    [12] => 2013-12-08
    [5] => 2014-01-04
    [10] => 2014-01-11
    [0] => 2014-01-12
    [13] => 2014-01-18
    [6] => 2014-02-01
)
```

To line up the charting tool I need to have it in a string like this.

```
 ============== Backstroke 50 =================
51.08,52.50,55.48,47.56,44.51,49.46,47.12,42.52,40.94,42.97,41.36,45.16,40.59,37.67,37.70Create or Render Chart

"2012-11-04","2012-11-10","2012-11-25","2012-12-01","2012-12-08","2012-12-15","2013-01-19","2013-11-03","2013-11-09","2013-11-10","2013-11-16","2013-12-01","2013-12-08","2014-01-12","2014-02-01"

============== Freestyle 50 =================
45.33,50.12,37.01,36.73,39.94,39.77,34.22,34.93

"2012-11-04","2012-11-25","2013-11-03","2013-11-10","2013-12-01","2014-01-04","2014-01-12","2014-02-01"

============== Freestyle 100 =================
137.73,126.86,133.65,124.14,121.94,121.10,130.99,118.27,122.44,131.38,115.95,120.06

"2012-11-04","2012-11-10","2012-12-08","2013-11-03","2013-11-10","2013-11-16","2013-12-01","2013-12-07","2013-12-08","2014-01-04","2014-01-11","2014-01-18"

============== Medley 100 =================
146.66,143.88,137.37,133.05,134.69,145.29,130.15,130.92,129.33,130.81,128.57

"2012-12-01","2013-01-19","2013-11-03","2013-11-09","2013-11-10","2013-12-01","2013-12-07","2013-12-08","2014-01-12","2014-01-18","2014-02-01"

============== Butterfly 50 =================
46.82,43.66

"2013-12-08","2014-01-12"
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the array #3 assumed. To be inserted in all of these list above. Example: butterfly has two dates. But I want to show all dates, and insert void times for the dates. This will allow the line getting rendered on the chart to be full use of the dates being displayed.

Here is the code:

First Array: Plus third array below this while:

```
        while($result->fetchInto($data,DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
            $count ++;
            $stroke = $data['stroke'];
            $distance = $data['distance'];
            $start = mysql2date($data['start']);
            $dateARR[] = $data['start'];
            $stroke = trim($c->getStrokeName($stroke));
            $strokestr = $stroke . " " . $distance;
            if($strokestr != $lastEvent) {
                $strokeARR[] = $strokestr;
                $lastEvent = $strokestr;
            }
            $lastEvent = $strokestr;

        }
        $dateARR = array_unique($dateARR);
        asort($dateARR);
```

Second Array:

```
while($result->fetchInto($data,DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
                $stroke = $data['stroke'];
                $distance = $data['distance'];
                $start = mysql2date($data['start']);
                $time = $c->integer2time($data['time']);
                $time = str_replace(':', '', $time);
                $meet = $data['meet'];
                $stroke = trim($c->getStrokeName($stroke));
                $strokestr = $stroke . " " . $distance;
                $timeARR[$strokestr][$data['start']] = $time;
                $count ++;
            }
```

Should or how to make use of the while loop two in the second array and insert missing dates. Should I prefill the dates then compare during the loop to place the time or the VOID of time while building timeARR?

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out now.

```
// Loop through Stroke and add all dates.       
    foreach ($strokeARR as $key1 => $val1) {
        print "$key1 = $val1\n";
        foreach ($dateARR as $key2 => $val2) {
            print "$key2 = $val2\n";
            $TestARR[$val1][$val2] = "VOID";
        }
    }
```

I had to loop through and prefill with full date range then pre fill with VOID.
When I enter the second while loop I end up inserting time where needed. worked out. I wish I can do this in one pass but I am not that good.